# Swift: call function from storyboard view controller I presented?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Ok, Ive tried the usual methods here but can't figure out this relatively simple issue -

I have a view controller that I present here:

```
self.presentViewController((self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("createEvent"))!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And I need to call a function in my original main VC from this createEvent VC. I have tried putting:

```
weak var superv: MainViewController!
```

in the create event class then doing something like this:

```
let create = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("createEvent")
create.superv = self //error here
```

Then in create doing:

```
superv.updateThings()
```

But I get an error trying to tie the presented VC to my MainViewController. What am I doing wrong here?

I have seen use of protocols but I would like to avoid that. What is the simplest way to do this?

This is what I did:
In main:

```
var create = UIViewController()
create = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("createEvent"))!
        create.delegate = self //error here
```

In create:

```
 weak var delegate: CreateEventDelegate!
protocol CreateEventDelegate: class {
    func doSomeFunction ()
}
```

And the error is `value of type uiviewcontroller has no member delegate`

The function in main I need to call is:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use protocols. I know you said you don't want to but its so simple and convenient.
In your createEvent vc:

```
weak var delegate: CreateEventDelegate!
```

Then at the bottom of the file (outside the create event VC class)

```
protocol CreateEventDelegate: class {
    func doSomeFunction ()
}
```

Then in the main VC class conform to the `CreateEventDelegate` protocol and add this:

```
create.delegate = self
```

Then you can call `delegate.doSomeFunction()` in your create event VC

Comment: I am getting an error (please look at the edit in my question) and also where do I write what needs to be executed my mainviewcontroller when doSomeFunction() is called by create?

Comment: the function in main that I need to call deals with a specific object.. If I define the function in this separate protocol how do I reference this object (its a tableview)

Comment: Regarding the error: `create` is an ordinary `UIViewController` and has no idea what "delegate" is. You need to cast it as a `CreateEventViewController` (assuming that's what the class is named). In that case you would put `create = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("createEvent"))! as! CreateEventViewController`

Comment: And with regard to where to write the code in `doSomeFunction()` you would write this in your main view controller: `func doSomeFunction() {self.tableView.reloadData()}`

Comment: Still getting error setting creates delegate to Main- what am I doing wrong? please look at my question for the error

Comment: you need to conform to the CreateEventDelegate Protocol. At the top of the file where you have `class MainViewController: UIViewController` or something like that, change `UIViewController` to `UIViewController, CreateEventDelegate`